# How to replace AngularJS $watch() mechanism with Angular way to monitor service's field change?

Tags: angular

Hi I have build previously AngularJS app that works with Google API.

For simplicity sake, here is the code...

GoogleAuth service - used to authenticate against Google

```
namespace AppDomain {

    const API_KEY = 'XXX';
    const DISCOVERY_DOCS = ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest']; 
    const CLIENT_ID = 'XXX'; 
    const SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'; 

    export class GoogleAuth {
        isSignedIn: boolean;

        static $inject: string[] = ['$rootScope'];
        constructor(private $rootScope: ng.IRootScopeService) {
            gapi.load('client:auth2', () => this.initClient());
        }

        private initClient() {
            gapi.client.init({apiKey: API_KEY, discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS, clientId: CLIENT_ID, scope: SCOPE})
                .then(() => {
                    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(isSignedIn => {
                        this.isSignedIn = isSignedIn;
                        this.$rootScope.$apply();
                    });
                    this.isSignedIn = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get();
                    this.$rootScope.$apply();
                });
        }
        signIn() { gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn(); }
        signOut() { gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut(); }
    }
    angular.module('app').service('GoogleAuth', GoogleAuth);
}
```

GoogleService service

```
namespace AppDomain {

    export class GoogleService {

        static $inject: string[] = ['$http', '$q', '$sce'];
        constructor(private $http: ng.IHttpService, private $q: ng.IQService, private $sce: ng.ISCEService) { }

        getGmailMessages() {
            // using gmail gapi to retrieve gmail messages, works only after user signs in
        }
    }
    angular.module('app').service('GoogleService', GoogleService);
}
```

And GmailComponent component

```
namespace AppDomain {

    class GmailComponent {
        public bindings: any;
        public controller: any;
        public controllerAs: string;
        public templateUrl: string;

        constructor() {
            this.controller = GmailController;
            this.controllerAs = 'vm';
            this.templateUrl = '/app/gmail/gmail.component.html';
        }
    }

    class GmailController {
        isSignedIn: boolean = false;
        messages: any[] = [];

        static $inject: string[] = ['$scope', 'GoogleAuth', 'GoogleService'];
        constructor(private $scope: ng.IScope, private auth: GoogleAuth, private service: GoogleService) { }

        $onInit() {
            this.$scope.$watch(() => this.auth.isSignedIn, isSignedIn => { 
                this.isSignedIn = isSignedIn; 
                if (isSignedIn) this.getGmailMessages(); 
            });
        }

        getGmailMessages() {
            this.service.getGmailMessages().then(messages => {
                this.messages = messages;
                this.$scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    }
    angular.module('app').component('gmailComponent', new GmailComponent());
}
```

As you can see in GmailComponent I am using `$scope.$watch(() => this.auth.isSignedIn, ...`

This allows to watch the IsSignedIn field of AuthService, so, once the user Signs In using Google, GmailComponent will be notified and will immediately call getGmailMessages() method. getGmailMessages() method will call GoogleService's getGmailMessages() that will load messages from Gmail account of currently signed in user. But it will only work after the auth cookie is created as a result of user sign in.

**Question:** - I want to rewire this AngularJS app in Angular. What is the proper way to implement with "$watch()" in today's version of Angular? Thanks.

Basically I want GmailComponent to react to a change of AuthService's isSignedIn field's value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `BehaviorSubject` to get notified when the value changes. A BehaviorSubject saves the last value and sends it immediatly whenever it is subscribed to. In your Auth service you can emit a value when the signed in status changes and then your component will be notified that the value has been updated. Example:

GoogleAuth service

```js
class GoogleAuth {
  private signedInSubject = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  public get isSignedIn() {
    return this.signedInSubject.asObservable();
  }

  private initClient() {
    gapi.client.init(...args)
      .then(() => {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(isSignedIn => {
          this.signedInSubject.next(isSignedIn);
        });

        const isSignedIn = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get();
        this.signedInSubject.next(isSignedIn);
     });
  }

   signIn() { gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn(); }
   signOut() {
     gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
     this.signedInSubject.next(false);
   }
}
```

GmailComponent

```js
class GmailController {

  constructor(private auth: GoogleAuth) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.auth.isSignedIn.subscribe(isSignedIn => { 
      this.isSignedIn = isSignedIn; 
        if (isSignedIn) this.getGmailMessages(); 
     });
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `get` and `set` keyword of Typescript along with Observables for this.

Let's say your property is `isSignedIn`. You make it private, and expose it via a `get` and `set` function, like so:

```
private _isSignedIn: boolean;

get isSignedIn() {
    return this._isSignedIn;
}

set isSignedIn(newVal: boolean) {
    this._isSignedIn = newVal;
}
```

This will allow you to access the property exactly as you normally would, i.e.:

```
myService.isSignedIn = true;
```

But it also allows us to do whatever we want within that `set` function. Let's add an `Observable` so we can get notified whenever the value changes:

```
private _change = new Subject<boolean>();
change$ = this._change.asObservable();
```

Within the `set`, we can now emit, like so

```
set isSignedIn(newVal: boolean) {
    this._isSignedIn = newVal;
    this._change.next(newVal);
}
```

And within the component, you can subscribe to the changes, like so:

```
myService.change$.subscribe((newVal) => {
    console.log("The value has changed to ", newVal);
});
```